Mutistop flight to Mexico on F1 visa
Asking for a friend.
He has a valid US F1 visa and he is wondering if he could take a multi stops flight to Mexico and get out of the airport and get back to travel to next destination within Mexico using the Mexico visa exemption program for US visa holders. Here is the itinerary for traveling from US and multiple stops in Mexico:
‌
Chicago • ORD -> Monterrey • MTY (get out of airport and stay in the city for a night)
Monterrey • MTY -> Mexico City • NLU (get out of airport and stay in the city for a night)
Mexico City • NLU -> Tulum • TQO (stay for 5 nights)
Tulum TQO -> Chicago US
TIA and Happy Travels!!

Domestic flights will not have immigration checks. Your friend will need to go through immigration in MTY. According to the Mexican consulate in Toronto, a valid US visa exempts from a need for a valid Mexican visa. It doesn't state anything about a type of US visa. However, the Mexican embassy in Finland has a slightly more detailed version of the same text:

Foreign nationals, regardless of their nationality - exempt holders of UK travel documents (blue or black)- holding a valid  USA B1/B2 visa, UK C- visitor visa, Canadian visitor visa, Japanese visitor visa or Schengen C-visit visa stamped in a valid passport, provided that the visa is to be issued for multiple entries and continues to be valid during the intended period of stay in Mexico do not require a visa to travel to Mexico as non-lucrative visitors.

This seems to suggest that an F visa won't be enough to satisfy the requirements.

Thank you. It's the domestic flight from within Mexico that he is most worried about. It’s good to hear that there will be no immigration checks for domestic. This is what it stays on Mexican Consulate in Chicago https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/chicago/index.php/visas-to-mexico/visas-english
If you wish to travel to Mexico as a tourist, in transit or for non-remunerated activities, for a period of less than 180 days, you DO NOT NEED A VISA if you are a holder of: an unexpired visa (any class) from Canada, the United States of America, Japan, UK or any country pertaining the Schengen Space

This is very strange that different consulates have conflicting information.

@littleadv in my experience it's pretty common that different consulates have conflicting information. It makes it hard to find information that applies globally and in each case.
